# Did the symbols of star in Christianity and Judaism originate independently?

Tags: judaism

In the literature of Christianity, the symbolic drawing of star is a pentagram picturising a five-pointed star. Judaism, on the other hand, uses hexagram that is, a six-pointed star . I wish  to know whether the symbolic representation of star in Christianity and Judaism originated and/or evolved independently. Views of any denomination are most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It would certainly seem that the symbols came about independently.
[Symbols in Christian Art and Architecture](http://www.planetgast.net/symbols/stars/stars.html) says of the two stars:

> The five-pointed star is the star of Bethlehem. Shaped roughly like a human being, it represents Jesus' incarnation.
>   The Christian five-pointed star should be distinguished from the pagan pentagram, which is formed of five lines which intersect. Most often shown upside down, the pentagram is associated with satanic ritual.
>
> Num. 24:17 "I see him, but not now; I behold him, but not near. A star will come out of Jacob; a scepter will rise out of Israel. (NIV)
>
> Matt. 2:1 After Jesus was born in Bethlehem in Judea, during the time of King Herod, Magi(n) from the east came to Jerusalem 2 and asked, "Where is the one who has been born king of the Jews? We saw his star in the east(n) and have come to worship him."
>
> The six-pointed star is the Creator's star. Its six points stand for the six days of creation. The points are also said to represent the six attributes of God - power, wisdom, majesty, love, mercy and justice. This star is also known today as the Star of David, and is a symbol of modern-day Israel. The six-pointed star is of ancient origin and is used in many religions with a variety of meanings.